# Add class to a div after doing location.search and decodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, encodeuricomponent

I want to add a class "active" to the `<li>` when this clicked (like a tab). The coffeeScript will search URL and reset the hash URL to provide content to the page. I use `$("."+key).addClass("active")` to add class when each tab is selected. but the initial value of key is undefined, so in javaScript console it appears  jQuery `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:. .`

How to give an initial value to key in this case since the page is always reloaded after `location.search`?

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
      <li class = "sherlock"><img src="logo1.png" ></a></li>
      <li class = "aesop"><img src="logo2.png" ></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
  key = decodeURIComponent(location.search).replace("?","")

  $("."+key).addClass("active")

  $("nav").on "click",".sherlock", ->
    key = "sherlock"
    location.replace("#")
    location.search = encodeURIComponent(key)


  $("nav").on "click",".aesop", ->
    key = "aesop"
    location.replace("#")
    location.search = encodeURIComponent(key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if key is not undefined before going on:

```
key = decodeURIComponent(location.search).replace("?","")

    if (typeof key !== "undefined"){
        // your code here.
    }
```

You can also use `if (key){//Your code here }` if key is defined elsewhere but may be empty or null.

Comment: Or `if(key?)` since this is CoffeeScript.